# R - Write a HTML file from URL/HTML Object/HTML Response

Tags: web, rvest, httr

I want to save a HTML file using a URL from R.
I have tried to save the response object(s) after using `GET` and `read_html` functions of `httr` and `rvest` packages respectively, on the URL of the website, I want to save the HTML of. But that didn't work out to save the actual contents of the website.

```
url = "https://facebook.com"
get_object = httr::GET(url); save(get_object, "file.html")
html_object = rvest::read_html(url); save(html_object, "file.html")
```

Neither of these work to save the correct output (i.e, the HTML content of the webpage in a .html file) of the actual website in the HTML file.

Comment: What is the "correct" output and what are you getting?

Comment: The correct output that I am looking for is the HTML content of the webpage in the `file.html` file

I am getting some junk inside the `file.html` file.

Answer (score 9):

Use `str(object)` to figure out what you are working with. In both cases, you were trying to write non-text to a text file.

Here's how to get the text and write it using both of your libraries...

```
url = "https://facebook.com"

library(httr)
get_object = GET(url)
cat(content(get_object, "text"), file="temp.html")

library(rvest)
html_object = read_html(url)
write_xml(html_object, file="temp.html")
```