# How can I scrape the title from a class with RVEST?

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape all the smartphones names from a mexican retail web page.

I don't why my code is not working, because I've done this for similar web pages, apparently RVEST is not "reading" the "class" of the html code.

Using the Google Selector Gadget, I found that Smartphones names are in a class named ".name", so I tried this:

```r
url <- 'https://www.chedraui.com.mx/Departamentos/Tecnolog%C3%ADa/Telefon%C3%ADa/Celular/c/MC230202?siteName=Sitio+de+Chedraui&isAlcoholRestricted=false'
web <- read_html(url)

web %>%
  html_nodes('.name') %>%
  html_text()
```

But the result is: '' ''

The expected result is a vector with all the SmartPhones names.

Comment: It seems like those nodes are being created dynamically with javascript. If you just run the `web %>% html_nodes(".name")` part, you'll see that you don't have nodes for those products, so there's nothing coming up to pull text from. There are a lot of questions on using RSelenium or other tools that can help with scraping dynamic pages

Comment: @camile Thanks, I'll try with RSelenium :D

Comment: @QHarr Will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the response and you will see info under a different class

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://www.chedraui.com.mx/Departamentos/Tecnolog%C3%ADa/Telefon%C3%ADa/Celular/c/MC230202?siteName=Sitio+de+Chedraui&isAlcoholRestricted=false")
titles <- page %>% 
  html_nodes('.product__list--thumb') %>%
  html_attr(., "title")
```

Comment: But, how do you know that class "thumb" of ".product__list" will work?

Because I inspected into the html code, but all the features for each smartphone are in a <li class="product_item">

Comment: I inspected the actual html returned

Comment: How do you do that?, the way I inspect something is by click button and "inspect"

Comment: I used rvest to export html returned to text file Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631226/r-write-a-html-file-from-url-html-object-html-response  ,  https://www.google.com/search?q=rvest+write+html+to+file&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB815GB815&oq=rvest+write+html+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0l4.5917j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I also tend to use this tool to see what xhr is likely to return: https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

To find which class your HTML text belongs to without interacting with the webpage structure i.e. without using 'Inspect' on the webpage, you can use CSS selectors to search for HTML text, then access the class it belongs to with `xml2::xml_attrs()`.

Here's an example using 'Huawei' as text, which appears in one of your titles.

```
"https://www.chedraui.com.mx/Departamentos/Tecnolog%C3%ADa/Telefon%C3%ADa/Celular/c/MC230202?siteName=Sitio+de+Chedraui&isAlcoholRestricted=false" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(":contains('Huawei')") %>% # search for string. Note the separate types of quotations
  xml2::xml_attrs() %>% # show all the attributes the string belongs to
  purrr::map("class") %>% # pull just 'class' attrs from the list
  unlist %>% unique
```

You can also use wildcards to search for strings, e.g. replace `html_nodes(":contains('Huawei')")` with `html_nodes("*:contains('Huaw')")`